# testing exception messages with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

My phpunit test:

```
<?php
class TestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
        /*
         * @expectedExceptionMessage success
         */
    public function testExceptionMessage() {
        throw new Exception('success');
    }
}
```

The unit test is failing. Here's the output of phpunit:

```
There was 1 error:

1) TestTest::testExceptionMessage
Exception: success

/path/to/TestTest.php:8

FAILURES!                          
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

It seems to me that the test ought to be a success since the Exception message is success, which is what @expectedExceptionMessage is expecting?

Comment: Would you ever need to do this? Surely you would be testing if a piece of code throws an exception, not the test itself.

Comment: Add an annotation for `@expectedException Exception`.... `@expectedExceptionMessage` works ___in conjunction with___ `@expectedException`

Comment: @David Jones - it's just a demo. Would you rather I post a multi-MB code base with a whole lot of unit tests and say "why isn't it working??" or would you rather I isolate the problem as much as I possibly can and *then* post?

Comment: Not at all, but the code sample in the question made it look like you were throwing the exception in the test which was the source of my confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `@expectedException` annotation and it should work

```
/**
 * @expectedException Exception
 * @expectedExceptionMessage success
 */
 public function testExceptionMessage() {
    throw new Exception('success');
 }
```

Comment: It's not :( I'm running phpunit 4.4.0. Maybe that's not the version I need to be running?

Answer (score 2):

You need to alert PHPUnit BEFORE throwing it:

1. to expect the exception
2. to expect the specific message you're throwing.

```php
 public function testExceptionMessage() {

    $this->expectException(Exception::class);  
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('success');
 
    throw new Exception('success');

}
```